# C++ Pre-fix and Post-fix operator overloading for addition (+) (not ++ or --)

Tags: c++

I am writing a `Complex` class for an assignment in which one of the methods should overload the default addition operator when adding a double to the complex number.
So far, I have the following code which correctly works for `c+5` where `c` is some `Complex` object

```
Complex& Complex::operator+(const double& d) const
{
    return Complex(real + d, imag);
}
```

However, it doesn't like it when I do `5+c`. I think it might be because of a prefix post-fix thing but I am not sure.

My question is if there is a way to also overload the `+` operator so that I can do something like `5+c`. I tried searching for a solution online but the only answers I could find dealt with the increment/decrement operators where you just add an int argument for the post-fix. I tried the same thing for `+` but it doesn't work.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Make it a free-standing operator (define outside if the class, if you need to, make it a `friend`).

Comment: In the linked duplicate, scroll down to "Binary arithmetic operators"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options come to mind:

1) Implement two non member functions:

```
Complex operator+(const Complex& lhs, double rhs);
Complex operator+(double lhs, const Complex& rhs);
```

2) Make `Complex` implicitly constructable from `double` (if it isn't already), and implement a single non-menber:

```
Complex operator+(const Complex& lhs, const Complex& rhs);
```

Comment: I see. Is there no member function option? Thank you very much by the way

Comment: @sshashank124 Not really, because a member has an implicit first parameter of type `Complex`.